# Improve behavior of remove item in Marionette.ItemView

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I've just started exploring world of `Backbone.Marionette` with a book by David Sulc and there is a project on GitHub with ContactManager app I am working with.

My goal is to improve the behavior of removing items. The remove item event is [here](https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/list/list_view.js#L64). My goal is to run this event only when item is removed, not when filtering contacts. I've tried to use `CollectionEvents`, but `fadeOut` don't work when I place in it.

I jsfiddled my question. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2L5x20vn/9/)

Comment: Welcome to Marionette! Please include the code snippet you are having troubles with directly in your question. This way, in the future others will be able to learn from your question even if the links are no longer good.

Comment: @AndrewHubbs, I updated question and add jsffidle example. Thanks for yout remark!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem.
Solution is to pass special `deleted` attribute to the model and analyze it in `remove` event.

```
        remove: function() {
            var self = this;
            if (this.model.get('deleted')){
                this.$el.fadeOut(function() {
                    Marionette.ItemView.prototype.remove.call(self);
                });
            }
            else {
                Marionette.ItemView.prototype.remove.call(self);
            }

        }
```

So, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2L5x20vn/23/)